# Bootstrap 4 Beta nav not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

FIXED: Was custom CSS, not bootstrap at all :/

This nav worked a few days ago but now it won't display the items on `xs`and `sm` screens when I toggle it. Everything works om md and up.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md nav-margin-md navbar-dark bg-dark">

            <div class="navbar-brand" style="font-size: 95%;">
                Brand
            </div>

            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navCollapse">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Container for all links and navbar content -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-margin-md">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Hjem</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./pages/bilder.html">Bilder</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link disabeled" href="./pages/about.html">Om Oss</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link disabeled" href="./pages/services.html">Tjenester</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav> <!-- /navbar -->
```

Comment: Can you please add your code to https://jsfiddle.net/ with external resources

Comment: @Znaneswar, I would but can't figure out how to add the bs4 cdn.

Comment: Replace `navbar-expand-md` to `navbar-expand-lg` and let me know once

Comment: Didn't work for me, still no difference at all.

Comment: Resize the output box here https://jsfiddle.net/eh3j7cfw/1/ and see the difference when small size it will show toggle and in md and lg it will show full nav

Comment: No, wanted the toggeler to work, I found the error though, wasn't bootstrap but custom css :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss any of required file for the bootstrap 4 beta.For this, you need a `jquery.js` and `tether.js` files.

[check your code here](https://jsfiddle.net/itsaddy/k2c824a1/2/)